# How to parse JMeter jmx file in node js

Tags: node.js, json, xml, jmeter, jmx

I'm trying to parse JMeter jmx file in node js to extract only Httpsampler. Could you please share any leads ?

So far I have tried parsing it as XML file, also converting it to as json file. Not able to get the desired element in both the method.